# Monitor clipboard access

Tags: windows-7

Whenever I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> on a folder in Windows 7, it shows me that it is cutting it out (it's a little whiter then before) but then after 1 second, it's out of the clipboard, just gone.

That's why I never can cut/copy folders.

**Is there a possibility/utility to track which applications are accessing the clipboard?**

Please don't extend this topic with virus-related stuff.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Do you know if STRG is the same as CTRL on an English Keyboard?

Comment: If you use `msconfig` to disable all startup programs and reboot, can you replicate the issue? Clearly something's messing with the clipboard and overwriting its previous contents (i.e. the name/path of the file/folder that you tried to cut).